# AMD CPU Instruction Set

Tags: assembly, x86, instruction-set, amd-processor

There is an AES instruction or a DRNG instruction of the Intel CPU.
I would like to know if there is such an instruction on the AMD CPU or similar command.
Or is there a web site where i can get information about this?

Comment: Off-topic here. Did you google that?

Comment: yes! but, I can not find a page for cpu command information

Comment: Then, take more time in searching the web. I have been able to find that information. http://ref.x86asm.net/

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: that link is just an opcode table for the instructions, nothing about which CPUs support them.  You're looking for pages like https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen which list supported extensions (and a bunch of microarchitectural details) for a specific microarchitecture, e.g. showing that AMD Zen does indeed support RDSEED and RDRAND, and AES-NI.  For actual CPUID dumps from specific models, see http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/